# Creating a indexed multi-dimensional array in [R] from a 2x2 dataframe

Tags: data-binding, r, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-dimensional data.frame with panel data (individual observations over a period of time).  I believe this would be more useful if I created a 3-dimensional array containing the same data with dimensions: date, individual, values.

So my approach is to isolate specific dates within the existing 2x2 dataframe and then stack these slices on top of each other to obtain the 3-dimensional array.  However, each slice has a different number of rows, so the 'abind' function is not allowing me to stack them.

```
# create example data frame
df1 = cbind(rep(8,12),c(rep(4,4),rep(3,4),2,2,1,1),
rep(2010,12),c("John","Frank","Bill","Anne","John",
"Frank","Bill","Anne","John","Frank","John","Frank"),
1:12,90:79,41:52)

df1 = data.frame(df1)
names(df1) = c("MM","DD","YR","Individual","Value1","Value2","Value3")

# the 'cube' function isolates a specific MM/DD/YR 'slice'
# Later I will attempt to stack the slices to get a 3-d array.
cube = function(MM,DD,YR) {
df2 = df1[df1$MM == MM & df1$DD == DD & df1$YR == YR,]
df2
}

# specify some parameter values
m = 8
d = c(1:4)
y = 2010

# apply 'cube' function to all date combinations specified
# by parameters m, d, y

out = apply(expand.grid(m,d,y),1,
function(x,y,z) cube(x[1],x[2],x[3]))

out = array(out)
k = dim(expand.grid(m,d,y))
z = data.frame(out[1])

require(abind)

# specify function that will transform 2-d data.frame into 3-d array.
for (i in 2:k[1]){
p = data.frame(out[i])
z = abind(z,p,along = 3)
}
```

The error message I get when I run the loop is:

```
Error in abind(z, p, along = 3) : 
  arg 'X2' has dims=4, 7, 1; but need dims=2, 7, X
```

I am using the CRAN package 'abind'.

Question: Is there a way to get the 'abind' function to stack unequal sized slices on top of one another?  Or, is there a more efficient way to create the desired array?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by a "2x2 data.frame". Read naively this sounds like 2 rows and 2 columns (which can't be what you mean, I don't think). It would be really helpful if you could provide a small reproducible example.

Comment: OK; the code now includes a reproducible example.

Comment: Does the new answer do what you want?

Comment: Yes; it does - thank you.  However, when I use it with my real dataset (not the reproducible example), I get an error that I'm trying to figure out. When I 'melt' the data, it says: "Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default", and the result is an array with a bunch of 0's, 1's, and 2's.  When I figure it out I will re-post.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely rewritten (thanks for the example).
I rewrote your example data to be slightly more compact.

```
df1 <- data.frame(MM=rep(8,12),DD=c(rep(4,4),rep(3,4),2,2,1,1),
                  YR=rep(2010,12),
                  Individual=c("John","Frank","Bill","Anne","John",
                    "Frank","Bill","Anne","John","Frank","John","Frank"),
                  Value1=1:12,Value2=90:79,Value3=41:52)
## create composite date variable
df1 <- transform(df1,date=as.Date(paste(YR,MM,DD,sep="/")))
## drop date components
df1 <- subset(df1,select=-c(MM,DD,YR))
library(reshape)
m <- melt(df1,id.var=c("Individual","date"))
cast(m,Individual~...~date)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to fill in spaces with NAs but want to have a "ragged" list, you can do this:

```
lapply(split(df1,df1$date),function(x) subset(x,select=-date))
```

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful but not exactly what I am looking for.  I've added reproducible code to my answer (above).  I think your method works when there is only one "Value" per observation (date,subj).  But I'm hoping that with a 3-dimensional array I can handle multiple values per observation.

Comment: What got it to work for my data was replacing your last line of code to have sum in the cast function:`cast(m,Individual~...~date,sum)` Thank you-